# # Python, Upload file in Dropbox using python

Tags: python, file-upload, dropbox

## Python, how find out the path of Dropbox and upload a file there

I want to upload daily csv file to dropbox account, but I'm getting ValidationError and others.

my code:

```
#finding the path
import pathlib
import dropbox
import os


# Automation is the name of my folder at dropbox

pathlib.Path.home() / "Automation"

Out[37]: WindowsPath('C:/Users/pb/Automation')



dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('My-token here')
dbx.users_get_current_account()


Out[38]:  FullAccount(account_id='accid', name=Name(given_name='pb', surname='manager', familiar_name='pb', display_name='pb', abbreviated_name='pb'), email='example@example.com', email_verified=True, disabled=False, locale='en', referral_link='https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/codigo', is_paired=False, account_type=AccountType('basic', None), root_info=UserRootInfo(root_namespace_id='1111111111', home_namespace_id='11111111'), profile_photo_url='https://dl-web.dropbox.com/account_photo/get/sssssssssssssssssss', country='US', team=None, team_member_id=None)


# Now trying to see something in the folder, I just want upload file there

response = dbx.files_list_folder(path='user:/pb/automation')
print(response)


for entry in dbx.files_list_folder('https://www.dropbox.com/home/automation').entries:
    print(entry.name)



ValidationError: 'user:/pb/automation' did not match pattern '(/(.|[\r\n])*)?|id:.*|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)'
```

Answer (score 1):

That error happens because the `path` parameter that the API is expecting needs to start with a '/'. It could be called out better in the docs.

Is the Automation folder in the root of your Dropbox directory? If so, then '/automation' should be sufficient for path. Try tinkering with the `/files/list_folder` endpoint in the [Dropbox API explorer](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#files_list_folder) until you find the correct path.

Your for loop is likely to throw an error too, though. Are you just trying to loop over the results of the list_folder call? I'd suggest changing to

```
for entry in response:
    print entry
```